# Transfer data from Form2 to Form1 is throwing System.Nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#

I have two forms form1 and form2 and I want to transfer the value from form2 to form1.
Form1 has a textbox where I want the value from Form2
 Form2 has a button on its click the value gets from textbox on form2 to the textbox on form1

Here is my code :

**Form2.cs**

```
private Form1 HandleToForm2;

public Form2(Form1 frmHandle2)
    {

        HandleToForm2 = frmHandle2;
        InitializeComponent();


    }

private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  

            HandleToForm2.WriteToTextBox2(textBox2.Text);
            this.Hide();
    }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public void WriteToTextBox2(string inputText1)

    {

       this.textBox8.Text = inputText1;

     }
```

Dont know why its throwing NullReference Exception "Object not set to an instance of an object

```
 HandleToForm2.WriteToTextBox2(textBox2.Text); //this line throws this exception
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: either `HandleToForm2` or `textBox2`is null - use the debugger to find out which.

Comment: We will need to see the code where you show your Form2. Maybe the key will be there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the `HandleToForm2` so it is null.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: HandleToForm2 or textBox2 is contains null. You can find it out, if you proceed like this:

Set a breakpoint on that line. Switch the Build Configuration to "Debug" and run the application in debug mode. When you reach the breakpoint, move the mouse over HandleToForm2 and VisualStudio show in a tooltip the value of that variable. Do the same with textBox2 and you will see which of those variables is not initialized.